# Javascript: How to automatically highlight the next events date

Tags: javascript, date

Every Saturday there is a event. I programmed it now only using HTML and CSS so no datebase. My problem is that I now need to adjust every week the list (replacing the span so the up coming event is highlighted so the vistors can see which date the next event is).

Is there a possible solution with Javascript to do this automatically?

Exemple: Today it is the 9 February so the event that is highlighted by the span tag is the 11 February.

When it is 12 February the span tag will be removed in the 11 February and the in the 18 February li will a span tag added so it is highlighted.

(I am learning javascript)

Thanks for helping me!

I have put the answer in the code!! Thank you every one to help me!

```js
    var $rootElem = document.getElementById('main-p');
    var $dateListEl = $rootElem.querySelectorAll('[data-date]');
    
    var currentDate = Date.now();

    for(var i = 0, len = $dateListEl.length; i < len; i++){


        var $li = $dateListEl[i];
        var date = $li.getAttribute('data-date');
        var ms = Date.parse(date);

        if(ms > currentDate){
            var text = $li.textContent; $li.innerHTML = '<span class="main-s1-a1-p1-span2-green">' + text + '</span>'
            break;


        }
    }
```

```css
    .main-p {
      font-family: 'Helvetica light';
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: 100;
      line-height: 140%;
      color: black;
    }
    .main-s1-a1-p1-span2-green {
      font-weight: 800;
      color: #93DD59;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  
 <body>

<ul id="main-p" class=" main-s3-a1-s1-a2-ul-info main-p">

        <li data-date="2017-02-5"> Zaterdag 4 februari</li>
        <li data-date="2017-02-12"> Zaterdag 11 februari</li>
        <li data-date="2017-02-19"> Zaterdag 18 februari</li>
        <li data-date="2017-02-26"> Zaterdag 25 februari</li>
        <li data-date="2017-03-5"> Zaterdag 4 maart: geen BS</li>
        <li data-date="2017-03-12"> Zaterdag 11 maart</li>
        <li data-date="2017-03-19"> Zaterdag 18 maart</li>
        <li data-date="2017-03-26"> Zaterdag 25 maart</li>
        <li data-date="2017-04-2"> Zaterdag 1 april</li>
        <li data-date="2017-04-9"> Zaterdag 8 : geen BS</li>
        <li data-date="2017-04-16"> Zaterdag 15 : geen BS</li>
        <li data-date="2017-04-23"> Zaterdag 22 april</li>
        <li data-date="2017-04-30"> Zaterdag 29 april</li>
        <li data-date="2017-05-7"> Zaterdag 6 mei</li>
       </ul>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are all the dates just hard coded into the page or are they actually coming from a database?

Comment: explain first how will you going to select the list item every week. If you mean by which event will be, that's pretty ambigous if you don't have any basis on how you can select the next event.

Comment: @Roljhon - I think they just want use the date.

Comment: @BSMP i think so, but the process aren't clear , maybe he could provide a better explanation on what will going to happen and what is the basis, like how will you say that this list item will be the next one? but thinking that should it now be highlighted or not yet? that's pretty confusing

Comment: @BSMP

Thx for the quick answer. 

Sorry for the incorrect explanation.

Comment: I have changed the question.

I hope it is better explained now.

Comment: Why don't you just highlight the first one if that is the next event? Say using CSS: `.main-p:first {font-weight: 800; color: #93DD59;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Html:
`<ul id="main-p" class="main-p">
    <li data-date="2017-01-16">Zaterdag 16 January</li>
    <li data-date="2017-01-17">Zaterdag 17 January</li>
    <li data-date="2017-02-25">Zaterdag 25 februari</li>
    <li data-date="2017-03-18">Zaterdag 18 maart</li>
    <li data-date="2017-04-01">Zaterdag 1 april</li>
</ul>`

Js:
`

```
var $rootElem = document.getElementById('main-p');
var $dateListEl = $rootElem.querySelectorAll('[data-date]');

var currentDate = Date.now();

for(var i = 0, len = $dateListEl.length; i < len; i++){

    var $li = $dateListEl[i];
    var date = $li.getAttribute('data-date');
    var ms = Date.parse(date);

    if(ms > currentDate){
        $li.classList.add('main-s1-a1-p1-span2-green');
        break;
    }
}
```

`

Example in Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/3PEVLctBNFpg8DhG2dBU?p=preview

Comment: Cool, but I think the OP wants to highlight the next date, so there needs to be logic to find out which one that is (it may not be the current date).

Comment: I have changed the question.

I hope it is better explained now.

Comment: @ Michiel I understand you, this implementation just is and does it. If you need it to wrap the text in the span then replace this line `$ li.classList.add ( 'head-s1-a1-p1-Span2-green');` to this `var text = $li.textContent; $li.innerHTML = '<span class="main-s1-a1-p1-span2-green">' + text + '</span>' `

Comment: @Smiranin Thank you, it works 90%!!!

But the only problem is that: Example: 

Saturday 21 Jan --> must be highlighted 
Saterday 28 Jan

When it is 20 JAN or 22JAN it goes to the right event, that is perfect!

But when it is Saturday 21JAN it highlight the next event. Instead it must highlight saterday21 and when it is 22JAN then it must change.

Thx for helping me so far!

Comment: @MichielWils As I said before, my English is not very good. And maybe I do not understand the intricacies of your question. Sorry.) But I think you can help the fact that atribute`data-date` we can write the same date (which we will use for the script to work properly), and in the text to write another date that the user will see. For example in the attribute will be recorded Saturday and in the text we will show Sunday.

Comment: @Smiranin

Thx you, my English isn't so good as well. I did what you said and it works now!! Thank you.          I just added 1 extra date tot the date-date so now when it works :D

Answer (score 0):

If the generated page always contains only the events to come and you want to simply highlight the first `li`, you can use css such as `first-of-type` (no need for the span)

```
.main-p > li:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #93DD59;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k90rrec5/)

(If the list can also contain dates of the past, the best solution would depend on how the page is build and how much influence you can exert on changing it.)